# Scala Value is not a member of Unit

Tags: scala

iam having small problem with my code, i make the code at java and its works but for some reason it wont work in Scala. any idea ?

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val in = new Scanner(System.in)
    var T: String = null
    var P: String = null
    var cand: String = null
    var pos: Int = 0
    var i: Int = 0

    System.out.print("Enter a text string T: ")
    T = in.nextLine()
    System.out.print("Enter a pattern string P: ")
    P = in.next()
    println()
    pos = 0

    while (pos <= T.length - P.length) {
      cand = T.substring(pos, pos + P.length)
      if (P == cand) {
        println(T)
        i = 0
        while (i < pos) {
          System.out.print(" ")i += 1 // Error : Value i is not a member of Unit
        }
        println(P)
        println()
      }
      pos += 1
    }
    in.close()
  }
}
```

Comment: i implements this code from a java Code that i wrote into scala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should break the line after `System.out.print(" ")` or use `System.out.print(" "); i += 1`. Otherwise, you are simply calling the member `i` on `System.out.print(" ")` which is of type `Unit`.

Comment: coool thanks , i just right the code and i coudnt see whats wrong :D, thabks a lot